# Removing a word from string starts with \U000

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I remove a word from a sentence that starts with  \U000 in PHP?

Example:

> Sentence: This a a sentence \U0001f525 bla bla

Output:

> This a a sentence bla bla

Got this from other post, but looks complected to me. Can you guys help me with it?

```
$output = preg_replace('!\b((https?|ftp)://)?www3?\..*?\b!', '', $input);
```

It removes `http://` or `https://` or `www.` or `www3.` or `ftp://` and ending with a white space.

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~\s*\bU000\w*~u', '', $s)`

Comment: Tried, Doesn't work

Comment: That preg_replace does something completely unrelated. You need to replace `\U000`? Then why doesn't your input string have that backslash?

Comment: Then please provide the exact string you are dealing with, add the code snippet to the question.

Comment: I edited the post, please check it out.

Comment: Try `\\U000\w+`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/nZpx2F/1

Comment: Saved my day, thank you very much. Post it as answer.

Comment: To match it as a whole word, you may use `preg_replace('~\s*\B\\\\U000\w*~', '', $s)` (and with initial whitespace). However, you have not really shown the string literal. There might be a better solution, but we need to know the root cause of the char corruption.

Comment: I actually my PHP script calls an api, but it contains those unicodes(emojis), which make json_decode unusable

Answer (score 1):

To match a literal backslash in a `preg_*` function you may do `\\\\`. Append a `U` to it it will match `\U` in an input string. `\w` means an alphanumeric character `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or underscore `_`. Putting all together you will have this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s*\\\\U000\w+/', '', $str);
```

`\w+` means a word character occurring one or more times (you may need `\w*` which also matches zero occurrence)

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZpx2F/1/)